# ANDROID - Using wifi interface (no internet) for network call while connected with mobile data (internet)

Tags: android, http

I am working with android device for POS system. I need to do data backup by uploading data to portable 4G router with tf card. In my device, I am getting internet from mobile data. There is no internet in my portable 4G router. I am only using it for backup purpose since my device doesn't have sd card slot.

Ok **please don't suggest anything other than my question**. This is the proof of concept i need to prepared. Other alternative, my colleague and I are already brainstorming.

DEVICE INFO

- connected with mobile data (have internet)
- connected with wifi (no internet)

GOAL

- to use wifi interface to upload data from device.

PROBLEM

- network call only using network interface with internet. In my case mobile data. I have no idea how to use wifi interface to make network call instead of using mobile data interface.

IMPORTANT

- device must always connected with mobile data and wifi
- cannot put sim card to wifi router. This is to prevent portable 4G router from being used as hotspot after working hours.

Comment: Do you want to check if internet is connected while using wifi?

Comment: internet is always come from mobile data. I do not need to check it. I want to use WIFI IP Address to post data to my 4G router with sd card that can used as a file sharing.